# Whats the best way to read files line by line and write them back with alterations based on lines satisfying certain conditions

Tags: node.js, file-io, file-handling

I need to read a file line by line and write newlines to same file while reading, if each line satisfy certain set of conditions. What could be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function (file, callback) {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, 'utf8', data) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        var lines = data.split('\n');

        fs.open(file, 'w', (err, fd) => {
            if (err) return callback(err)

            lines.forEach(line => {
                if (line === 'meet your condition') {
                    // do your write using fs.write(fd, )
                }
            })
            callback();
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use node fs module  with the help of fs you can perform operation asynchronously as well as synchronously. below is as an example of asynchronously

```
function readWriteData(savPath, srcPath) {
    fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //Do your processing, MD5, send a satellite to the moon or can add conditions , etc.
            fs.writeFile (savPath, data, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('complete');
            });
        });
}
```

Synchronously example

```
function readFileContent(srcPath, callback) { 
    fs.readFile(srcPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(data);
        }
    );
}

function writeFileContent(savPath, srcPath) { 
    readFileContent(srcPath, function(data) {
        fs.writeFile (savPath, data, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('complete');
        });
    });
}
```